# matlab-shell, changed files' location (changed files' directory)

Tags: matlab

[image]

I've been used mablab-mode & shell in GNU emacs, and changed some of files' location, then these warnings came out every time. There's no sort of setting location. Does anyone know this problem?

Warning : 
There does not exists or it's not directory.

Comment: Sounds like something got messed up while chaning "some of files' location", so you probably need to try and remember which files and how you changed their location.  You might also like to translate the messages into English.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I meant those files, which used in my project, don't need anymore, so moved to another folder. 

Messages : 
Warning : there doesn't exist the name, or it's not directory.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you were using some startup.m file? Check, and if so, you can change the path which refers to your moved files to the correct path. That might do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, updated matlab was the problem, and I solved it. Simply, initializing path.